# What is wrong with the solution of ${dy \over dx}={y^2+xy+x^2 \over{x^2}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\Large{dy \over dx}={y^2+xy+x^2 \over{x^2}}={(x+y)^2\over x^2}-{xy\over x^2}={x+y\over x} -{y\over x}=1+{y\over x}-{y\over x}=1$

hence $\large \int dy=\int dx$ and so $y=x+c$

Comment: $\frac{(x+y)^2}{x^2} \neq \frac{x+y}{x}$

Comment: use the substitution $y(x)=x\cdot u(x)$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=u(x)+x\frac{du}{dx}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Note $\frac{(x+y)^2}{x^2}\neq \frac{(x+y)}{x}$

Follow the right procedure as follows

We have $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2+xy+x^2}{x^2}$$ $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2}{x^2}+\frac{y}{x}+1=\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2+\frac{y}{x}+1$$

Let $\frac{y}{x}=v\iff y=vx\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=v+\frac{dv}{dx}$, we get 
$$v+\frac{dv}{dx}=v^2+v+1$$
$$\frac{dv}{dx}=v^2+1$$
$$\frac{dv}{v^2+1}=dx$$
I hope you can take it from here

Comment: OP had asked what is the mistake in his solution. Though you have given a complete solution, you have not answered his question